# Remove leading zeros in numbers *within a data frame*

Tags: r, dataframe

Edit: For anyone coming later: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, since it explicitely concerns work on data frames, not single variables/vectors.

---

I have found several sites describing how to drop leading zeros in numbers or strings, including vectors. But none of the descriptions I found seem applicable to data frames.

Or the `f_num` function in the `numform` package. It treats "[a] vector of numbers (or string equivalents)", but does not seem to solve unwanted leading zeros in a data frame.

I am relatively new to R but understand that I could develop some (in my mind) complex code to drop leading zeros by subsetting vectors from a data frame and then combining those vectors into a full data frame. I would like to avoid that.

Here is a simple data frame:

```
df <-  structure(list(est = c(0.05, -0.16, -0.02, 0, -0.11, 0.15, -0.26, 
-0.23), low2.5 = c(0.01, -0.2, -0.05, -0.03, -0.2, 0.1, -0.3, 
-0.28), up2.5 = c(0.09, -0.12, 0, 0.04, -0.01, 0.2, -0.22, -0.17
)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which gives

```
df
    est low2.5 up2.5
1  0.05   0.01  0.09
2 -0.16  -0.20 -0.12
3 -0.02  -0.05  0.00
4  0.00  -0.03  0.04
5 -0.11  -0.20 -0.01
6  0.15   0.10  0.20
7 -0.26  -0.30 -0.22
8 -0.23  -0.28 -0.17
```

I would want

```
est low2.5 up2.5
1  .05   .01  .09
2 -.16  -.20 -.12
3 -.02  -.05  .00
4  .00  -.03  .04
5 -.11  -.20 -.01
6  .15   .10  .20
7 -.26  -.30 -.22
8 -.23  -.28 -.17
```

Is that possible with relatively simple code for a whole data frame?

---

Edit: An incorrect link has been removed.

Comment: I believe the downvoter was quick to downvote, but didn't read the post. Or am I wrong? I explicitly referred to the many posts on removing leading zeros, but my question is on DATA FRAMES. The linked post which I am supposed to have duplicated doesn't seem to answer my question. Or does it?

Comment: You just need to apply given function of specified columns. There are lots of questions like that here on SO.

Comment: Thank you @PoGibas! Well, I searched and found no mentioning of data frames. I'm glad I asked, now others too will find that solution thanks to your comment.

Comment: I still don't understand you problem. Linked answer seems to be a solution for vectors. You just need to apply it on columns.

Comment: @cibr do `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", x)))`

Comment: And what did I do exactly? Did you go through the link I attached? It's a duplicated question.

Comment: @Sotos, I did go through that post, and many others. I didn't find a mentioning of data frames. I (and many others) are inexperienced r users. Linking to that post is fine, but since I explicitly referred to such posts and pointed out that I did not understand whether/how this could be applied to dataframes, you could have responded differently. For an advanced programmer it is a duplicate from a programming perspective. But then it's not a duplicate since I asked how/whether this method could be applied to data frames.

Comment: And the answer is: same way as for vectors you just need to iterate over the columns. You can use linked answer for vectors, data.frames, lists and other structures. Given solution won't change.

Comment: I will not get into a discussion with you. You clearly misunderstood both, my intentions and the way this site works.

Comment: In other words: don't post if you are an inexperienced user who doesn't yet understand how methods for vectors are applied to a data frame.  Even if your post will help others too.

Comment: This explains it: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."

Comment: Please do not delete this post, duplicated posts **are** useful. SO welcomes everyone beginner or not. But do not take downvotes/close votes personally, give it time this post is only 5 hours old.

Comment: Thanks @zx8754. I will not delete it. For inexperienced users, this is not a duplicate. (Asking how to apply the original posts to a data frame.) I have learned not to take SO downvotes personally, but your comment is nice and welcome. BTW, for anyone using the approach suggested by Ronak Shah: it doesn't work well with data frames that also include columns with text (like mine does, but the example I used did not).

Comment: Your link is referencing a C# question, not an R question. Anyhow: What is your intention with dropping the leading zeros? The give example `data.frame` contains numerical data (`str(df)`), so you cannot drop leading zeros (like in the case of strings) but just change the visible presentation of the numbers... Or do you want to convert the numeric values into strings in your data.frame?

Comment: @R Yoda. APA format (American Psychological Association, publication manual) requires tables with standarised estimates to include no leading zeros. And... you are quite right in noting the problem of numerical data and conversion to strings when dropping leading zeros. That caused a lot of trouble for me, so I decided to stick with unstandardized estimates even for this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am interpreting the intention of your question is to convert each numeric cell in the `data.frame` into a "pretty-printed" string which is possible using string substitution and a simple regular expression (a good question BTW since I do not know any method to configure the output of numeric data to suppress leading zeros without converting the numeric data into a string!):

```
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df,
                         function(x) gsub("^0\\.", "\\.", gsub("^-0\\.", "-\\.", as.character(x)))),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2
#    est low2.5 up2.5
# 1  .05    .01   .09
# 2 -.16    -.2  -.12
# 3 -.02   -.05     0
# 4    0   -.03   .04
# 5 -.11    -.2  -.01
# 6  .15     .1    .2
# 7 -.26    -.3  -.22
# 8 -.23   -.28  -.17

str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ est   : chr  ".05" "-.16" "-.02" "0" ...
# $ low2.5: chr  ".01" "-.2" "-.05" "-.03" ...
# $ up2.5 : chr  ".09" "-.12" "0" ".04" ...
```

If you want to get a fixed number of digits after the decimal point (as shown in the expected output but not asked for explicitly) you could use `sprintf` or `format`:

```
df3 <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub("^0\\.", "\\.", gsub("^-0\\.", "-\\.", sprintf("%.2f", x)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3
#    est low2.5 up2.5
# 1  .05    .01   .09
# 2 -.16   -.20  -.12
# 3 -.02   -.05   .00
# 4  .00   -.03   .04
# 5 -.11   -.20  -.01
# 6  .15    .10   .20
# 7 -.26   -.30  -.22
# 8 -.23   -.28  -.17
```

**Note:** This solution is **not** robust against different decimal point character (different locales) - it always expects a decimal point...

Comment: Thank you, R Yoda. Your code works fine, and is a solution to the problem I introduced. A text column (not included in my example) is still dropped, but that's easy to solve. As you correctly note, the numeric cells are coverted to strings, which is not a good thing in my particular case; I use knitr and kableExtra to develop tables.  (I can only hope that @Sotos and others learn to be less judgemental.)